# Error message on startup of Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to get rid of this error-message: (remote-server send an error: (404) Not found)? Every time I start Excel 365 under windows 10 this nasty error pops up:[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer myself: a commerical statistics-addin was going mad. When I am deactivating this (and only this) COM-Addin, the error-message no longer pops up. Hopefully the vendor has a solution for this.